# systemd falsly reports service as masked and it is not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, systemd

I am trying to mask a service using `sudo systemctl mask expressvpn.service` and the outout comes as `Failed to mask unit: File /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service already exists.`.

I tried These solutions:

1. `sudo systemctl unmask expressvpn.service` then `sudo systemctl mask expressvpn.service`. It did not work.
2. file `file /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service` and it outputted `/etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service: ASCII text`. this indicates that the file is not a symblic link.
3. `sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service` and it outputted `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/systemd/system/expressvpn.service': File exists`
4. `systemctl status expressvpn.service` and it outputted `Running`.

I do not have a clue about why is that happening, all i can do is rename the service into another name (for example `expressvpn.service.old`) and it works but this issue happened several times with another program called anydesk and other programs as well.

So briefly, where is the link file stored? how to solve the problem without renaming the service?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mask unit files that are stored in /etc, because **they're in exactly the same location** as the 'mask' symlink would go to.

The "mask" subcommand exists so that the system owner could override units that were installed by a package to /usr/lib – it makes systemd pretend the unit doesn't exist even though it does. But if the original unit is in fact in /etc, then there's no point in masking it: you can just remove it to get the same result.

- If the unit was installed by you, then just rename or remove it – it's out of scope for the "masking" feature. (However, `--runtime` mask might still work if that's actually what you want?)
- If the unit was in fact installed by a .deb package, then the package should be fixed to only install files to /lib or /usr/lib instead.
- If the unit was installed by an "~/Downloads/install-expressvpn.sh" script, best practice is to not use such scripts.

Comment: So briefly, you mean that there is no best practice, rename it or remove it... as i wish?